# a java exception has occured while opening .jar file

Tags: java, exception, jar, exe

[image]

While execute the jar file. i found this exceptions. But when i tried to double click the .jar file. It shows [image]

if anyone know whats the error. just tell me..

Comment: Hi search it over google first

Comment: The answer to your question is in the error messages. Please research them in more depth, and if you still can't solve your problem do ask again, but be prepared to show your work.

Comment: @KevalDalasaniya i search it over google. some one told that it might be version problem. The swing application you develop it in some other java version and compile it in some other version. so only problem like i searched over the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who Got this error "Java Exception Has Occurred" Try this

I tried the solution in Netbeans. While creating a jar file for swing applications.  Your .jar file is placed inside the dist folder. Inside the dist folder you have one lib folder and your .jar folder.

Just select the two lib and jar files and copy and paste in some other new folder. And now you double click your jar file. now your jar file is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your jar needs the Jcalendar classes to be executed properly...
is the Jcalendar. jar in the classpath??

Comment: Yes i added the jcalendar-1.4.jar. While executing it in the netbeans i dont get any error. After taken into jar only i got this type of error.

Comment: @Aoryouncellvan, try to check if reference to JCalendar are absolute or relative??